# How to separate these elements in html/css

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, responsive-design

In my work project we need to leave a similar space between these buttons. They only overlap in the process of becoming responsive. My superior and I have tried many forms of css and slds stuff and have not achieved anything

[image: Normal Buttons]

and this picture are the collapsed buttons

[image: responsive collpased buttons]

Are components inside into lightning-card
[image: responsive buttons]]

HTML Buttons

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows class="displayInline">
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="PISCINAS" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter" data-name="piscinas" data-id="botonPiscina"
                icon-name="utility:flow">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="SOCORRISMO" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter tabletFloatCenter" data-name="socorrismo" data-id="botonSocorrismo"
                icon-name="utility:help_center">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="CONSERJERÍA" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class="  slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter tabletFloatRight" data-name="conserjeria" data-id="botonConserjeria"
                icon-name="utility:key">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="LIMPIEZA" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter" data-name="limpieza" data-id="botonLimpieza"
                icon-name="utility:magicwand">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="JARDINERÍA" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter tabletFloatCenter" data-name="jardineria" data-id="botonJardineria"
                icon-name="utility:classic_interface">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="MANTENIMIENTO" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter tabletFloatRight" data-name="mantenimiento" data-id="botonMantenimiento"
                icon-name="utility:custom_apps">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="OBRAS" title="Primary action with lighter look"
                onclick={getButtons} class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_left mobileFloatCenter" data-name="obras" data-id="botonObras"
                icon-name="utility:thunder">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item class="pcDisplayMargin" size="12" small-device-size="8" medium-device-size="8" large-device-size="5" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Seleccionar todas" title="Primary action" onclick={getButtons}
                class=" slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_right" data-name="todos" data-id="botonTodos"
                icon-name="utility:multi_select_checkbox" >
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
```

and this is the CSS

```
/*----------MOBILE-------------*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobileFloatCenter {
    float: none !important;
  }
}

/*----------TABLET------------*/
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .tabletFloatRight {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabletFloatCenter {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabletFloatLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/*----------PC------------*/
.pcDisplayMargin{
  /*display: flex !important;
  margin: 0.05% !important;*/
}

.pcDisplayInline{
  display: inline !important;
}

.marginButtonsFilters{
  margin: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: The alarm bells rang when I saw you were using float. This will probably break the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements are not completely clear, but I will give it a go! What I understand is that you want to create space between the buttons. When the horizontal distance is not enough, the buttons should wrap into a new row. As mentioned in one of the comments above, the float is probably not the best solution for this. Instead, I think it is better to use the layout component to arrange the items automatically as described here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/example

Next, you have a decision: should the buttons form equal columns, or should they maintain equal horizontal spacing?

**Option 1 - Equal horizontal spacing**

Remove all extra classes, styles, and size properties.

[image]

```
<template>
  <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
      <lightning-button
        variant="brand-outline"
        label="PISCINAS"
        title="Primary action with lighter look"
        onclick={getButtons}
        data-name="piscinas"
        data-id="botonPiscina"
        icon-name="utility:flow"
      >
      </lightning-button>
    </lightning-layout-item>
   ...
  </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

**Option 2 - Grid columns (12 columns)**

Add size properties to all the layout items to control how many columns they should span (1-12) for the different device sizes.
[image]

```
<lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="6" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="2">...</lightning-layout-item>
```

**Option 3 - Fixed width columns**

Style the layout items with a fixed width (or use a CSS class)
[image]

```
<lightning-layout-item style="width: 186px">...</lightning-layout-item>
```

**Option 4 - Fixed width + equal buttons**

Same as above but also make the buttons 100% wide.
[image]

```
<lightning-button style="display: grid; width: 100%">...</lightning-button>
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!!, it has helped me, I have combined everything you have said and I have obtained the result that I wanted.